# What is a vector with squared terms with respect to a regular vector?

Tags: functions, vectors

Suppose there is a vector $\mathbf y$

$$\mathbf y=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3\end{bmatrix}$$
A vector squared is a dot product, just a scalar. So then, what is the function to get
$$f(\mathbf y)=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1^2 \\
y_2^2 \\
y_3^2 \end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: Not sure I get the question.  You can have functions from, say $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$, no problem.

Comment: But you've written it down explicitly!  If, say, $\vec y=(1,2,3)$ then $f\left( \vec y\right)=(1,4,9)$.

Comment: The function $f$ as you have it defined seems to fit your request.

Comment: @VaneVoe The function $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by $$f(\mathbf x) = \langle x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2 \rangle$$ _is_ a perfectly valid function. Could you be more explicit about what sort of answer you are expecting? How would you define a vector valued function?

Comment: @VaneVoe Could you please clarify what you mean by "what function makes that transformation"? The phrasing of your question suggests that you are looking for a function that squares each component of a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. If this is not the case, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @VaneVoe And what is unaccepted about the function $f$ as defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no standard function that does this - we can build one that does this job in the way you describe: set

$$f(y) = (y_1 ^2, \ldots)$$

and this is a function.

We can, however, achieve this via a Hadamard product, a pointwise matrix product. Again, a bit nonstandard, but doable.

Comment: Hmm, I anticipated a matrix transformation but I am not quite sure what you are saying specifically. If I have a differential equation that contains, say, components of both the original vector $y$ and then this new vector with squared terms, I thought I could separate it into these two distinct vectors , one with linear components and one with squared components, and solve it. But if the function is this niche, there must be a simpler way to do it, perhaps there is a kind of substitution that will get rid of squared components?

Comment: Unless we use the diagonal matrix whose entries correspond to those of $y$ I see no way of achieving what you desire. Does this arise in a particular context? Give us more details if this is the case so we can better help you.

Comment: I have no problem with a diagonal matrix, I see vectors like this come up sometimes in differential equations and physics. See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161207/how-can-one-solve-a-differential-equation-with-polynomial-vector-componentsnoredirect=1#comment6509533_3161194

Comment: Such equations are nonlinear and my best guess would be to use a numerical method.

Comment: I've seen explicit solutions to these types of equations before involving exponential functions, I just don't know how the authors derived them.