# How can one solve a differential equation with polynomial vector components?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose there is a differential equation in the form of

$$\mathbf y'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1+y_1^2 \\
y_2+y_2^2 \\
y_3+y_3^2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
What is the general method of finding the solution to such an equation? For a vector of purely linear terms, as in $$\mathbf y'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 &1 & 0\\
0 &0 &1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \end{bmatrix},$$ the general solution is $$\mathbf y(t)=e^{At} \mathbf x_{0},$$ but I am not sure what the general solution or method is for a vector with non-linear components.

Or, suppose an even simpler case:
$$\mathbf y'(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1+y_1^2 \\
y_2\\ \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: We can attempt to separate variables, i.e. $\frac{dy_1}{y_1+y_1^2}$ and work from there.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving $y_k'=y_k+y_k^2$ separately.

Comment: Okay, would you treat each equation separately and solve each separately, then recombine the solutions into a single vector at the end? But then how do you divide only one component of a vector by only one other component of a vector to achieve $\frac{dy_1}{y_1+y_1^2}$? Is there a name for this method? Because this kind of linear separation has to of required some proof. I don't understand why I have not encountered this partial separation method before when working with a purely linear vector, it seems much simpler.

Comment: We go entry by entry since each does not depend on others, i.e. $y_1$ does not depend on $y_2$ or $y_3$. We're not dividing by components, rather we are breaking this apart and reading three equations.

Comment: Oh okay, so it is only works because the system is decoupled.

Comment: Exactly therefore.

Comment: That makes sense then. Suppose the system in $R^2$ wasn't decoupled and the $y_1^2$ was in the second component instead. Is there some substitution that can be made to linearize that and solve the system like an ordinary linear system?